# XSLT - Checking if the previous value of the field (Date and Grant) is same as the current value and adding

Tags: xml, xslt

I am facing a couple of problems with my XSLT (Pasted below).

I am trying to add the Grant_Value field if the Grant_Date and Grant_Value are same (XML Pasted below)

Using the preceding-sibling function, I am able to trim down the rows so that the rows with the same Grant_Date and Grant_Type are displayed only once but the Grant_Value corresponding to those rows needs to be summed together and I am not able to that, the problem is that there can be many rows with the same Grant Date and Grant Value so the Grant Value corresponding to all of them needs to be added together.

Secondly,

I need to count the final number of rows\records displayed. When I am using the count function, it is giving me the incorrect value (It is displaying the records which were not part of the preceding-sibling test condition also, may be because it works on the XML). There is some other problem too so is there a way I can put up a counter in the for-each loop to give me the correct value? A Counter Variable may count number of times the for-each loop iterates and could be of some help.

Lastly,

I need to remove the Linefeed after the last record, I have used the position function for that but again it doesn't work fine due to the preceding-sibling function. Again I think, that because this works on XML data, I am not getting the correct value if I am using the preceding-sibling condition, without that, it works fine.

XML data:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ne:NODE xmlns:ne="namespacene" >
    <ne:NODEEntry>

        <ne:RECORD>GRANT</ne:RECORD>

        <ne:Grants>
            <ne:GRANT_DATE>20140402</ne:GRANT_DATE>
            <ne:GRANT_TYPE>GRANT1</ne:GRANT_TYPE>
            <ne:GRANT_VALUE>20000</ne:GRANT_VALUE>
        </ne:Grants>

        <ne:Grants>
            <ne:GRANT_DATE>20140402</ne:GRANT_DATE>
            <ne:GRANT_TYPE>GRANT1</ne:GRANT_TYPE>

            <ne:GRANT_VALUE>20000</ne:GRANT_VALUE>
        </ne:Grants>

        <ne:Grants>
            <ne:GRANT_DATE>20140403</ne:GRANT_DATE>
            <ne:GRANT_TYPE>GRANT1</ne:GRANT_TYPE>

            <ne:GRANT_VALUE>25000</ne:GRANT_VALUE>
        </ne:Grants>

        <ne:Grants>
            <ne:GRANT_DATE>20140402</ne:GRANT_DATE>
            <ne:GRANT_TYPE>GRANT1</ne:GRANT_TYPE>

            <ne:GRANT_VALUE>20000</ne:GRANT_VALUE>
        </ne:Grants> 

    </ne:NODEEntry>

</ne:NODE>
```

XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:ne="namespacene"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent='no'  omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text"/>


     <xsl:template match="ne:NODE">      

                <xsl:for-each select="ne:NODEEntry">
                <xsl:variable name="Record" select="ne:RECORD"/>

               <xsl:for-each select="ne:Grants">

                   <xsl:if test ="not(preceding-sibling::ne:Grants[ne:GRANT_DATE/text() = current()/ne:GRANT_DATE/text()]) and not(preceding-sibling::ne:Grants[ne:GRANT_DATE/text() = current()/ne:GRANT_TYPE/text()])" >

                <xsl:value-of select="$Record"/>               
               <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>                              
                <xsl:value-of select="ne:GRANT_DATE"/>
                   <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="ne:GRANT_TYPE"/>
                   <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>      
                <xsl:value-of select="ne:GRANT_VALUE"/>
                           <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">                                                        
                          <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>    
                           </xsl:if>
                   </xsl:if>    
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(ne:Grants)"/> 
                </xsl:for-each>     
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT Expected Output:

```
GRANT|20140402|GRANT1|60000
GRANT|20140403|GRANT1|25000
2
```

2 is the total number of rows in the Output file.
The last field(in first 2 rows) sums up all the Grant_Value with the same Grant_Date and Grant_Type. In this case, the date 20140402 and type GRANT1 appear thrice in the XML hence the Grant_Value corresponding to them should be summed together, i.e 20000 + 20000 + 20000 = 60000

Current Output on running the above files:

```
GRANT|20140402|GRANT1|20000
GRANT|20140403|GRANT1|25000
4
```

Here we are getting 4 as that is the actual number of rows in XML (including the duplicate entries for the first row) but that is not what we need, we want 2 should be there.
And, the cursor should actually be after the last record (25000 in this case) , it should not go to next line. To explain it better, 4 should be just adjacent to the last record 25000 instead of going to the next line, in this case.

Could someone please help me out, I am totally stuck with them. Thanks a lot in advance.

Please don't mind the poor formatting, it is my first time here, really looking forward to it.

Comment: I have corrected your formatting (You need to make sure normal text doesn't begin with 4 spaces or more). It would help though if you showed the output your expected in this case, as then it is easier to see what the problem is. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if you are indeed using XSLT 2.0, you might want to read up on the xsl:for-each-group command, as it may be what you need. http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1314.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have added the output expected and the current output in the question. I am not sure how for-each-group would be of help in this case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of this as a grouping problem, because you are actually grouping together elements with the same **GRANT_DATE** and **GRANT_TYPE** values. In XSLT 2.0, you would make use of the **xsl:for-each-group** here

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="ne:Grants" group-by="concat(ne:GRANT_DATE, '|', ne:GRANT_TYPE)">
```

Within this look you will be positioned on the first distinct element (based on date and type), so the inside of the loop will be just the same as you have currently. The main difference is with how you get the total for all the records in the group. This can easily be done by using the "sum" function together with "current-group()" (which returns all the nodes in the group).

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/ne:GRANT_VALUE)"/>
```

In terms of getting the total record, you can also make use of the **distinct-values** function.

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(ne:Grants/(concat(ne:GRANT_DATE, '|', ne:GRANT_TYPE))))" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" xmlns:ne="namespacene" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output indent='no' omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="ne:NODE">      
      <xsl:for-each select="ne:NODEEntry">
         <xsl:variable name="Record" select="ne:RECORD"/>
         <xsl:for-each-group select="ne:Grants" group-by="concat(ne:GRANT_DATE, '|', ne:GRANT_TYPE)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Record"/>               
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>                              
            <xsl:value-of select="ne:GRANT_DATE"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
             <xsl:value-of select="ne:GRANT_TYPE"/>
             <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>      
             <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/ne:GRANT_VALUE)"/>
             <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>    
         </xsl:for-each-group>
         <xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(ne:Grants/(concat(ne:GRANT_DATE, '|', ne:GRANT_TYPE))))" />
     </xsl:for-each>     
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should output the following

```
GRANT|20140402|GRANT1|60000
GRANT|20140403|GRANT1|25000
2
```

EDIT: If you need have multiple **NODEEntry** elements, then this variation of the XSLT may work to take into account the **RECORD** in the grouping too

```
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" xmlns:ne="namespacene" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output indent='no' omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="ne:NODE">      
      <xsl:for-each-group select="ne:NODEEntry/ne:Grants" group-by="concat(../ne:RECORD, '|', ne:GRANT_DATE, '|', ne:GRANT_TYPE)">
          <xsl:value-of select="../ne:RECORD"/>               
          <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>                              
          <xsl:value-of select="ne:GRANT_DATE"/>
          <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
           <xsl:value-of select="ne:GRANT_TYPE"/>
           <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>      
           <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/ne:GRANT_VALUE)"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/> 
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(ne:NODEEntry/ne:Grants/(concat(../ne:RECORD, '|', ne:GRANT_DATE, '|', ne:GRANT_TYPE))))" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, I was not aware of the for-each group functionality! I guess the distinct-value count should work (as of now it is not working on my actual file though, will check that). Can you help me with figuring the first part (summing the value based on the similar grant date and type). In this case 60000 should be displayed instead of 20000 in the first row in output.

Comment: My apologies, I had forgotten about the total of the values. I have edited my answer to show this now. It is easily done by using the "sum" function on the "current-group()"

Comment: Hi Tim, Sorry for my delayed response and thank you, the current-group function is working perfectly fine. However, I am having some problem with the count function. It works fine in this case but if we have more than 1 record say GRANT2 and they have the same value for GRANT_DATE and GRANT_TYPE, then that records will not be a part of the count so we need to concatenate the Record field - ne:RECORD also along with the date and type but since the field ne:RECORD is at a different node level than the GRANT_DATE AND GRANT_TYPE,

Comment: contd.. I placed the value of ne:RECORD in a variable and tried concatenating using $variable-name but somehow that value is not getting picked and hence it is not getting included in the count. Secondly, I am trying to use the  position() function to remove the space after the last record in the output file but that doesn't seem to work (Ideally the last 2 should be printed immediately after the last record 25000 in the output).

Comment: I've added a slight variation to the XSLT to the answer to show how you can possibly include the ne:RECORD in the grouping. I am not sure about the issue with the "space after the last record" as I don't get any spaces! However, you can always check "position() != last()" perhaps?

Comment: Wow! it worked, I was trying to get the values using variables but it wasn't working and somehow the position() function was also not working but this time it did work! Can thank you a thousand times for the help and it won't be enough :) Thanks !